# Spring 4.2 Creating bean with gerneric Information

Tags: spring, generics, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I am not sure it is possible what I want to do. I try to improve my generic code to reduce number of parameters because theoratically only one information is needed.

Currently I have a constructor like:

```
protected _AbstractDataOnDemand(
            final Class<T> entityClass, 
            final CrudService<T> service, 
            final ApplicationRepository<T> repository,
            final JPAPersistableDODPopulationUtilizable<T> dodPopulation
    ){
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.service = service;
        this.repository = repository;
        this.dodPopulation = dodPopulation;
    }
```

As you can see it could be enough to give entityClass as information and create instances of service, repository, dodPopulation with that information.

I would like to do something:

```
protected _AbstractDataOnDemand(
            final Class<T> entityClass, 
    ){
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.service = createCrudService(entityClass);
        this.repository = createRepository(entityClass);
        this.dodPopulation = createDodPopulation(entityClass);
    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: why not to overload your constructor ?

Comment: Hey Kuhajeyan, I guess my question was not clear, I edited my question